# How do I add a setuptools entry_point as an example in my main project?

Tags: python, setuptools

I want to make my program pluggable.  I'd like to use the setuptools way of doing so, using eggs.

I've been able to make a plugin to provide an alternate class for some functionality, and I can use it.

I would like to select the class to use at runtime; either the one in my core module or in any of the plugins.  I'd like to use the pkg_resources way of querying for these classes:

```
for entrypoint in pkg_resources.iter_entry_points("myapp.myclasses"):
```

How can I create an EntryPoint object for my class in core, and register it, so that iter_entry_points will return it the same way as for my .egg plugin class ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`pkg_resources.iter_entry_points` lists any entry points by the given name in any egg, including your own package. Thus, if your `entry_points` entry in `setup.py` lists the following, *and* you've run `setup.py develop` to generate the metadata, your own entry point will be included:

```
[myapp.myclasses]
classentry1 = myapp.mymodule:myclassname1
classentry2 = myapp.mymodule:myclassname2
```

The [Babel project](http://babel.edgewall.org/) does exactly this; in it's [`setup.py`](http://babel.edgewall.org/browser/trunk/setup.py) it lists entry points for both `babel.checkers` and `babel.extractors`, and these are looked up by [`babel.messages.checkers:_find_checkers`](http://babel.edgewall.org/browser/trunk/babel/messages/checkers.py#L162) and [`babel.messages.extract:extract`](http://babel.edgewall.org/browser/trunk/babel/messages/extract.py#L204), respectively.

If you do not want to have a `setup.py` file (which is easy enough to create and/or generate from a template), then you are facing having to alter the internal state of `pkg_resources.working_set` instead:

- `working_set.entries` is a list of eggs. You'll have to add the path of your project's top-level directory to this.
- `working_set.entry_keys` is a mapping from paths in `entries` to a list of package names. Add your project as `working_set.entry_keys[path] = ['package.name']
- `working_set.by_key` is a mapping from package name to a `pkg_resources.Distribution` instances. You'll need to create a `Distribution` instance and store it under your package name: `working_set.by_key['package.name'] = yourdistribution`.

For your purposes the `Distribution` instance can be fairly sparse, but I'd include at least the project name. You'll need to have a entry-point map on it though:

```
yourdistribution = Distribution(project_name='package.name')
yourdistribution._ep_map = {'myapp.myclasses', {
    'classentry1': entrypointinstance_for_classentry1,
    'classentry2': entrypointinstance_for_classentry2,
}}
```

The internal structure `_ep_map` is normally parsed on demand from the egg-info metadata.

Please note that this is relying entirely on undocumented internal data structures that can change between versions. In other words, you are on your own here. I'd generate a `setup.py` file instead, and run `python setup.py develop` to generate the egg metadata instead.

Comment: I don't have a setup.py and prefer not to switch to one - is there any way I can do this programatically ?

Comment: *Why* won't you have a `setup.py` file? It's trivial and painless to add one.. I suspect that a lot of things that `pkg_resources` does will break without a local egg metadata structure at least..

Comment: Because the main project is autotools-based, and duplication of information between configure.ac and setup.py isn't my idea of a good time.  Are you saying it cannot be done programatically ? I can obviously create a pkg_resources.EntryPoint, but how do I make iter_entry_points() aware of it ?

Comment: Not easily, you need to alter the internal state of `pkg_resources.working_set` to add your "distribution" (data structures normally taken from your metadata) manually. I count 4 lists and dicts that need updating.

Comment: I worked out something similar to your answer but avoiding private members like _ep_map.  It was so complicated that I decided to attack the problem from the other side instead, creating a static EntryPoint dummy class with enough info for it to work in the above for statement by changing it to: for entrypoint in [ep, ] + list(pkg_resources.iter_entry_points("myapp.myclasses")):